# Object + class names as variable (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got an error, if I try this:

```
var Box = $(window.parent.document).find("#box"); // works fine
var BoxContent = $(Box+" .bg > .content").text(); // error

console.log(BoxContent);
```

Error message ("Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] .bg .content")

What is my fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Box` isn't a string, you can't meaningfully concatenate it with a string to create a new selector.

It's a jQuery object, so you can use `.find()` to search within it.

```
var BoxContent = Box.find(".bg > .content").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
var BoxContent = Box.find(".bg > .content").first().text();
// OR
var BoxContent = Box.find(".bg").first().find(".content").first().text();
```